# Can't Access SQLite DB on Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, azure, iis, connection-string

I have created an ASP.NET MVC web app which uses an SQLite database under EF6.

The app works fine in VS.  The database is included in the project in the App_Data folder.  When I publish to Azure (or an IIS test server on the LAN) I get an error.  The Azure instance is showing an **HTTP 500** error, and it only happens on views which require database access to load.  Other than that it works fine.  The IIS test server shows an error saying **unable to open database file.**  I tried loosening file permissions on the .db file on the IIS instance, but nothing changed.  I'm not sure how to go about doing anything on the Azure instance.

Can someone please assist me with debugging a SQLite connection problem on Azure/IIS?

**Details**

- VS 2015 Enterprise
- Azure app services (free tier, production server)
- SQLite3 database
- IIS on Windows Server 2012R2 (test server)

I have tried all sorts of combinations of connection strings:

- setting a connection string to the `D:/xxx/xxx path` in Azure Portal
- modifying the connection string in the deployment profile in VS (replaces value in web.config upon deployment)
- just leaving it all the same

Nothing has worked or even changed the error.  Perhaps one of those configurations is able to access the file but simply can't open it (which is sort of what the IIS error suggests, I think).  Even then, how do I go about finding out?

**EDIT**
On the IIS test server I discovered that the entire problem was that the connection string in Web.config was wrong.  I manually edited it on the server and it fired right up.  I'm still not sure how to correct the path on the Azure server, nor how to correct my deployment settings in VS to inject the correct path.  Thoughts along those lines are still appreciated.

**EDIT 2**

I've also found that each time I hit a page requiring DB access, I see this error show up in the application logs on Azure:

> 2017-01-03T20:25:32
>   System.ApplicationException: The trace listener AzureBlobTraceListener is disabled. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The SAS URL for the cloud storage account is not specified. Use the environment variable 'DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL' to define it.
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.RefreshConfig()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: [Shoot back](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). Anyway, find out what user IIS runs as, and what the permissions on the file *and* all directories are; and try to open the file and create a new file, and log exceptions.

Comment: @CL. I tried disabling inheritance on the .db file and then giving the IIS_IUSRS permission to read/write the file.  I tried various configurations on the folder as well.  I even tried giving "everyone" full access, but that didn't work.  Even if I got it working on IIS, I'm not sure how to remedy the problem on Azure.  Any thoughts there?

Comment: You have to find out what the actual error is. See the last part of my previous comment.

Comment: @CL further discoveries have altered the question.  Please see edits above.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some abysmally slow debugging sessions, I finally remembered that in toying around I had set a connection string value in the Azure portal.

**Apparently whatever value is set in the Azure Portal overrides (at runtime?) the values in the Web.config file**

I simply deleted the connection string from the Azure Portal (your app/Application Settings/Connection Strings)  and it worked.  The final connection string looks like this:

```
 <add name="yourThingEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/cadb_SQLite.csdl|res://*/cadb_SQLite.ssdl|res://*/cadb_SQLite.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string=&quot;data source=D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\yourSQLiteDBFile.db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

To get the Web Deploy working in VS, you'll need to edit the publish profile to have a connection string matching the format

```
data source=D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\yourSQLiteDBFile.db
```

Apparently not many people use SQLite for web apps, and most people should not.  If you ever expect more than one user for your website at a time, you shouldn't fix SQLite, you should convert to SQL Server CE or just full-blown SQL Server which Azure will take care of for a paltry $5/mo.  Choose wisely!

Comment: Here ya are using SQLite for a web app and you still feel obligated to give the "don't use it" disclaimer :)  SQLite is fine for most light apps in wal mode.

Comment: +1 For mentioning WAL mode.  That actually became an important discovery later on when SQLite couldn't handle the concurrency needs of the app.  Finally we switched to SQL Server anyway, but we tried WAL and the performance was almost 50% better if I remember correclty

Comment: I hear the Berkeley DB variant of SQLite handles concurrency even better, but I'm still confused on if it supports T-SQL or is a NOSQL variant.  I love MS SQL server and use it in business all the time, but for little projects having an in proc file based fairly powerful DB really appeals to me.  Firebird embedded  looks good as well as it supports stored procs and such, but doesn't seem like a lot of people are using it.  I think SQL Server CE was a little bit too good so MS pulled development for it. Anyway so far SQLite in WAL mode is working well for what I need and is easy to use.